# Python: Printing all permutations of list while maintaining order and sequence

Tags: python, math, combinations, permutation

The question is as follows: Given a list of integers (1-n), print all the permutations of lists while maintaining order and sequence.

Ex: lst = [1,2,3] (n is 3 in this case)

output:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2]
[2,3]
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

What's going on here is that the largest group is printed first (includes all the integers up to n), and only 1,2,3 would be accepted since it maintains the sequence and doesn't change the order. Next the groups of two. In this case 1,2 and 2,3. Again the sequence is maintained. Finally the groups of 1 which will just be all the integers.

I am not sure how to go about solving this question since it is different from printing all permutations, which would make cases such as 2,1 and 3,2 acceptable; however this does not maintain sequence. Furthermore, 1,3 would not be accepted, since the number after 1 is 2.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `itertools.combinations` might be a starting point. Just skip combinations with gaps and repeat for all sequence lengths you need.

Comment: Do you need the result to be sorted by decreasing length or is is just for the explanation ?

Comment: These aren't permutations; they are (nonempty) elements of the power set of [1,2,3]. The *permutations* of `[1,2,3]` all have length 3, containing all the same elements of the original list but in unique orders: `[1,2,3]`, `[1,3,2]`, `[2,1,3]`, `[2,3,1]`, `[3,2,1]`, and `[3,1,2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over all possible start and end indices:

```py
lst = [1,2,3]
combo = []
for size in range(len(lst),0,-1):
  for start in range(len(lst)-size+1):
    combo.append(lst[start:start+size])
print(combo)
```

This outputs:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[2,3],[1],[2],[3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to work for me:

```
for x in range(len(lst)):
    for y in range(x+1):
        print(lst[y:y+len(lst)-x])
```

or using list comprehension:

```
finalList = [lst[y:y+len(lst)-x] for x in range(len(lst)) for y in range(x+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal number sequence from 0 to 2^list size - 1.
Map number to binary equivalent.
The bit position will correspond to list position.
1 will mean present. 0 absent.

```
mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n_elem = len(mylist)
n_seqc = (1 << n_elem)
sequencies = [[] for _ in range(n_seqc)]
for seq_idx in range(n_seqc):
    for i in range(n_elem):
        if seq_idx & (1 << i) > 0:
            sequencies[seq_idx].append(mylist[i])

print(sequencies)
```